# How to get incremental values running in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  a  sample Data  like  this

```
ID  RN 
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   4
1   5
1   6
1   7
500 8
500 9
500 10
500 11
861 12
861 13
861 14
853 15
843 16
```

I'm trying to get result  like  this

```
ID  RN OP
1   1  NULL
1   2   1
1   3   1
1   4   1
1   5   1
1   6   1
1   7   1
500 8  NULL
500 9   8
500 10  8
500 11  8
861 12  NULL
861 13  12
861 14  12
853 15  NULL
843 16  NULL
```

I have tried with row number but not  able to move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not doing this with tens of thousands of records at a time, you could try something like this:

```
SELECT src.`id`, src.`rn`,
       (SELECT MIN(z.`rn`) FROM `Running` z WHERE z.`id` = src.`id` and z.`rn` < src.`rn`) as `op`
  FROM `Running` src
 ORDER BY src.`rn`;
```

This will give you the result based on this source data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Running`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Running` (
    `id`        int(11)       UNSIGNED NOT NULL    ,
    `rn`        int(11)       UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `Running` (`id`, `rn`)
VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7),
       (500, 8), (500, 9), (500, 10), (500, 11),
       (861, 12), (861, 13), (861, 14),
       (853, 15),
       (843, 16);
```

Comment: `MIN(z.id)` should be `MIN(z.rn)`

Answer (score 1):

The efficiency of analysis functions is much higher than that of subqueries

row number

```sql
with tab1 as (
select 1 id, 1 rn union all
select 1 id, 2 rn union all
select 2 id, 3 rn union all
select 2 id, 4 rn union all
select 3 id, 5 rn union all
select 3 id, 6 rn union all
select 3 id, 7 rn union all
select 4 id, 8 rn 
)
select t1.*,
       case when row_number() over(partition by t1.id order by t1.rn) = 1 
         then null
         else min(t1.rn) over(partition by t1.id)
       end
  from tab1 t1
;
```

and another answer

```sql
with tab1 as (
select 1 id, 1 rn union all
select 1 id, 2 rn union all
select 2 id, 3 rn union all
select 2 id, 4 rn union all
select 3 id, 5 rn union all
select 3 id, 6 rn union all
select 3 id, 7 rn union all
select 4 id, 8 rn 
)
select t1.*,
       nullif(first_value(t1.rn) over(partition by t1.id order by t1.rn), t1.rn)
  from tab1 t1
;
```

There are more ways to write...

Comment: I would use `min()` instead of `first_value()`, but window functions should be the best approach.